# Is there a good way to copy text within parentheses in Vim?

Tags: linux, unix, vim, vi

I want to copy the parameters `foo(bar).baz` in the following code:

```
function(foo(bar).baz)
```

First attempt: Cursor on one of the parentheses, then `y%`. This gives me the parameters plus a bit extra:

```
(foo(bar).baz)
```

Second attempt: Cursor on opening parenthesis. Set a mark `ma`, jump to end with
 `%` then `` y`a `` to copy back to the mark. This gives me:

```
(foo(bar).baz
```

Setting a mark at the end and going the other way gives me exactly the same. Setting a
mark on the `f`, then typing `` mah%y`a `` *does* give me the `foo(bar).baz` that I want, but maybe there's something more concise. Is there?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use [text objects](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#text-objects):

<kbd>yi(</kbd> (or <kbd>ya(</kbd> if you want to include the parenthesis).

You can also use `"` to work inside quotes, etc. See the link for details, or type `:help text-objects` in Vim.

Comment: You could also use `yib` or `yab`. I find the parenthesis keys a little fiddly.

Answer (score 7):

A *slightly* shorter alternative to <kbd>yi(</kbd> is <kbd>yib</kbd>. Similarly <kbd>yiB</kbd> is equivalent to <kbd>yi{</kbd> - yanks the contents inside braces.

Personally I usually do <kbd>vib</kbd> (visual select the text inside braces) first to make sure that the expected text is selected, followed by a <kbd>y</kbd>.

For more text object goodness, see `:help text-objects`.

Answer (score 3):

Following should do it

**Yank Inner Block**

<kbd>yi(</kbd>